# How to get "Resolution" variable from testcase on an TFS/VSTS server

Tags: tfs, get, azure-devops, postman

I have a lot of testcases which are stored in my microsoft TFS server and i am trying to make changes to failed testcases via REST API. I am therefor trying to create an application which can get and patch (update) values from an Microsoft TFS server but i can't get or patch the "resolution" variable because it doesn't get parsed when i execute my get command. The resolution variable is the variable which declares what type of testfailure we are dealing with (Unknown/Testerror/ProductError).

I think i have to specify a filter which makes me able to extract it, but i am not so sure. I was hoping that someone could help.

This is my GET command which i execute in postman, but i dont add anything in the detailsToInclude field.

```html
https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/test/runs/{run}/results/{result}?api-version={version}[&detailsToInclude={string}]
```

I get almost every variable returned except the resolution variable which i wanna edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `detailsToInclude` parameter describe clearly:

> enum { None, Iterations, WorkItems}
>
> - None - **Return results with core fields values only.** Core fields    includes State, Outcome, Priority, AutomatedTestName,
>     AutomatedTestStorage, Comments, ErrorMessage etc.
> - Iterations - Return results with core field values and test iteration    details.
> - WorkItems - Return results with core field values and associated    workitems information.
>
> *[Source Link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/results#get-a-test-result)*

The rest API will only return core filed not every field. Instead, you could try to use SDK, client API to get test result.  How to please refer-- [TFS API: How to get latest test result for a test case](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18843.tfs-api-how-to-get-latest-test-result-for-a-test-case.aspx)

However, you could be able to use Rest API to [Update test results for a test run](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/results#update-test-results-for-a-test-run) with **resolutionState** parameter in Content-Type: application/json such as below:

```
PATCH https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/test/runs/{run}/results?api-version={version}

[
  {  
    "id": { int },
    "state": {
    enum { Pending, Queued, InProgress, Paused, Completed }
    },
    "computerName": { string },    
    "resolutionState": { string },
    "priority": { int },
    "failureType": { string }, 
    "owner": {
       "DisplayName": {string}
    },
    "runBy": {
       "DisplayName": {string}
    },
    "outcome": {
          enum { None, Passed, Failed, Inconclusive, Timeout, Aborted, Blocked, NotExecuted, Warning, Error, NotApplicable, Paused, InProgress}
    },
    "errorMessage": { string },
    "comment": { string },
    "startedDate": { DateTime },
    "completedDate": { DateTime },
    "durationInMs": { long },
    "associatedBugs": [ 
        {
         { "id" : {int} }
        } 
    ]
  }
]
```